# How do I use an existing Spring 3.0.5 project in STS?

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, project, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Unlike IDEA, which has options for using existing sources, STS doesn't look like it has options to use an existing project. I don't want to create a new project's source folders and bin folders. I already have a Maven POM and I want STS to just use that. How do I do that without messing up my existing project?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Could you try to do 'File/Import', you must see this menu entry:

[image]

If it's a maven project you can import using POM ('Maven Projects'), if it's an eclipse project you can use 'Existing Projects into Workspace'.